# Deployments for multiple environment in jenkins

Tags: deployment, jenkins

I want to use jenkins to deploy various WARs using our single script for multiple servers.
Could you please suggest how to pass servers name to a job, so that our script can take that as an argument and start deploying on the selected server? The solution will be used to deploy the same code to  10-20 servers using our customized ant script to build these projects.

**EDIT:** We are using AIX servers. Want to use a drop down menu from which user can select environment IP,Port. How should I approach this?:

1. Maintaining txt files of environments
2. Using choice parameter

On selection of this env, we will use this env variable in our shell script to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

To have one job start another, just use the [parametrized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). In addition, I like to run the deployment jobs on the target machine. For this I defined a slave for every target server. To be able to run a job on a specific slave and be able to choose the slave as a parameter, I use the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

If you want more specific tips, be more specific on what application servers you use. It would also be interesting to know if you operate under windows, linux, or other environment. The more info you give the better and more fitting the answers.